# Detect ctrl+a / cmd+a keycode on contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ciqewu/edit?html,js,console,output)

I am trying with

```
$('.container').on('keyup', function(e){                     
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

but its always the first key that is pressed!.

Note -  I want the detection to work on `keypress` as I am validating the div on each keypress

Answer (score 3):

You can use `event.ctrlKey` to check if the Controle-Key is pressed at the same time:

```
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65/*A*/) {
```

Comment: I did try that but it is always returning false

Comment: @Ajey Works: http://jsbin.com/retayulisa/1/edit?html,js,console,output does it work for you like that as well?

Comment: No sir still does not work, checked on windows and mac, the ctrlKey is false. What am I doing wrong. :(

Comment: @Ajey what Browser are you using. It should realy work when you are pressing controle and A and then release A first.

Comment: change the event to `keypress` for better because `ctrl` key never got up.

Comment: @Ajey yes I would also use keypress, do you need keyup?

Comment: using chrome 45, I am building a twitter like text validation so I need the logic to work on keyup rather than keypress

Comment: This was triggering both if and else condition. So i modified it to `if((e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65) || e.keyCode == 17 /*ctrl key*/) {` . this worked for me.